# Login Using Facebook and im facing FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult as IsCancelled true always in IOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11

I have Used Login using Facebook Feature in My App and Im getting FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult as IsCancelled always. This Issue occurs only in IOS 11. Is there any possibilities to solve this issue and Im Currently using Xcode 9 Beta with Facebook SDK 4.1.0. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest facebook SDK? There's a notice about a bug fix: `Fixed login bug that treated a request for no new permissions as a cancellation.` in the v4.9.0 release.

Comment: Thank you @petesh i will try now with 4.9.0

Comment: Im getting the following Error:-  The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8)

Comment: Hi, I am facing this issue too, i am having latest version '4.29.0'

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue by updating my FacebookSDK to 4.22.0

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.22.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.22.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.22.0'
```

Now it works fine with the Xcode 9 beta and IOS 11-developement version. And in IOS 11 safari will handle the login with facebook feature because from IOS 11 the default facebook, twitter are removed.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 11, be sure, that you don't set

```
    FBSDKLoginManager *facebookLoginManager = [FBSDKLoginManager new];
    [facebookLoginManager setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount];
```

because system account is no longer available.